# pandas 'DataError: No numeric types to aggregate'

Tags: python, pandas

It is a dataframe containing value for loan_status and gender

```
loan_df[['Gender','loan_status']].groupby('Gender' , as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='loan_status', ascending=False)
```

but it is giving following error:
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
when i write this code:

```
loan_df[['Gender','loan_status']].groupby('Gender' , as_index=False).mean()
```

even then it was giving same error ,please tell how to resolve it.

Comment: loan_status is having only two type of value: 0 and 1

Comment: What is the datatype in `loan_status`? Is it numeric? Please provide the output of `loan_df.dtypes`.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @Marcel on doing 'loan_df.info()' ,this has been shown 'loan_status'       346 non-null object

Comment: i found the answer,actually there was a part which was not numeric,thats why it is returning this